# Class structure for an SQL connection

Tags: c#, sql

I have a class structure for an SQL connection.

The connection seems ok but having trouble with the IEnumerable part with error underlining these:
SqlMapper.Query and _connection.Query

1 - "The name 'SqlMapper' does not exist in the current context"

2 - ".Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and no extension method 'Query' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Class1.cs

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SQL.Models
{
public class Connection : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection _connection;

    public Connection()
    {
        var connectionString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]);
        _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        _connection.Open();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Close();
        _connection.Dispose();
    }

    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Query(string sql, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
    {
        // this one works fine, without compile error, so I understand how to
        // workaround the error
        return SqlMapper.Query(_connection, sql, param, transaction, buffered, commandTimeout, commandType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string sql, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null)
    {
        // this one is failing with the error
        return (IEnumerable<T>)_connection.Query(sql, param, transaction, buffered, commandTimeout, commandType);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes I found this in a search for class structures for a MVC4 ddl

Comment: And how does MVC4 come into play here? THis code would be the same for a WPF application. Nothing in it at all is MVC specific - except maybe you having no clue how to properly tag something.

Comment: Based on your code sample and how you're describing the problem I'll guess that you're somewhat new to C#. Apologies if that's not the case. My recommendation is to abandon trying to roll your own data access library and use one of the many that have been developed by expert professionals instead.

Comment: Yes I am new to MVC4 and C# programming.  I would like to be able to use my SQL Tables from ASP.net 4.0 in my MVC Applications.

Comment: Search for "Entity Framework"

Comment: If you are already using this in ASP.NET 4.0 (I suppose you're referring to WebForms as opposed to MVC) there's no reason it shouldn't work. Get what's missing from an application that's compiling.

Comment: Does this use dapper dot net extension methods?